# How to verify ACL in a template

Tags: ember.js

How should a template lookup the user access to a specific route before displaying a link/action?

Considering the routes already contain a list of authorized roles, should a simple template helper/component lookup the view property and validates access?

( something like `{{#if has-access-to 'items.new'}}` ? )

Routes are currently "protected" using a simple ACL solution:

**AclRouteMixin**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var accountTypes = {
    1: 'member',
    2: 'manager',
    3: 'owner'
};

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    beforeModel: function beforeModel(transition) {
        this._super(transition);

        var accountType = this.get('session.accountType');
        var role = accountTypes.hasOwnProperty(accountType) ? accountTypes[accountType] : 'unknown';

        if (this.get('roles') && !this.get('roles').contains(role)) {
            transition.abort();
            this.transitionTo('unauthorized');
        }
    }
});
```

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, AclRouteMixin, {
    roles: [ 'manager', 'owner' ]
});
```

**EDIT**

Since the server knows the permissions it is much easier to include a `policy` object ( or per-entity properties ) than trying to duplicate the authorization logic.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzasJuhsTSs&index=13&list=PLLUBPLc28H8c8ihVHkYeRHe8OiB8P5WL0) might be relevant to you

Comment: Thanks @MilkyWayJoe, The video was really helpful. The server already implements the ACL and other rights management like it was done in the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzasJuhsTSs&index=13&list=PLLUBPLc28H8c8ihVHkYeRHe8OiB8P5WL0)  ( linked by [MilkyWayJoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54364/milkywayjoe) ) explains a really simple way to setup authentication / ACL.

The session object ( or each API response ) could contain a `Policy` object that contains `true`/`false` values.

**Template**

```
{{#if session.policy.canCreateItems}}{{link-to 'New Item' 'items.new'}}{{/if}}
{{#if item.policy.canEdit}}{{link-to 'Edit' 'items.edit' item}}{{/if}}
```

**Authenticator** ( if using `ember-simple-auth` )

```
var session = {
    userId: response.user_id,
    policy: {}
};

for(var p in response.policy) {
    if (response.policy.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        session.policy[p.camelize()] = response.policy[p];
    }
}
```

**API responses**

```
{
    "items": [{
        ...
        policy: {
            can_delete: true,
            can_view: true,
            can_edit: true
        }
    }],
    "policy": {
        can_create: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is load up the permissions on an auth route that all other routes extend, as for checking it and displaying links I went ahead with a component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Component = Ember.Component;

export default Component.extend({

  hasPermission: function() {
    var permission = this.get('permission');
    return this.get('auth.permissions').indexOf(permission) !== -1;
  }.property('permission')
});
```

As for the template:

```
{{#if hasPermission}}
  {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

And simply call it from links:

```
{{#can-do permission="view_tables"}}
   {{link-to "tables" "tables" class="nav__link"}}
{{/can-do}}
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After evaluating the different options I went with something close to the talk @MilkyWayJoe ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzasJuhsTSs&index=13&list=PLLUBPLc28H8c8ihVHkYeRHe8OiB8P5WL0 ) linked. The session object holds a `policy` hash with `canDeleteItem` and the template evaluates with a simple if: `{{#if session.policy.canDeleteItem}}{{/if}}`. The `policy` object could contain helper functions.

Comment: @MartinSamson haha yeah I saw it ^^